# routing assets from localhost

Tags: php, routes, xampp

I am trying to access to differents files (js, css, img...), but there is no way.  I use the route (for example):

```
<script src="/folder_1/folder_2/file.js"></script>
```

But allways get the same problem on the js console:

```
GET http://localhost/folder_1/folder_2/file.js
```

I tried to access directly to these files and the xampp response with a 404 code. But if I create a php file on this route, it works... for example:

```
http://localhost/folder_1/folder_2/file.php
```

And then it responses with the "hello this is a test" of an echo on the file.php.
What am I doing wrong?? or what I should to do to solve the problem??

Thankyou.

Comment: what is the extension of the file that you are including the js in?

Comment: What is the folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

and thanks to @Sourabh and @b0s3 for the quikly answer.
The solution I found is use the protocol on the "domain" (localhost is a domain??)
For example if I have this:

The html:

```
<script src="{public-route}/js/bootstrap.min..js"></script>
```

And on the php (after get the html template):

```
define("DOMAIN", "localhost");    
$template = str_replace ("{public-route}", DOMAIN."/public", $template);
```

It doesn´t work, but if I define DOMAIN:

```
define("DOMAIN", "http://localhost");
```

Thank you.